# User control in ASPX page not showing until IIS was reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, user-controls

During a demonstration of a project, a user control inside an ASPX page wouldn't load. Everything else on the page was able to load up just fine, we could navigate around the site etc.

Unsure of what to do, I reset IIS and it was properly displayed after refreshing the page.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? I need to explain to management the possible causes for this behavior and figure out if this is going to be something I need to worry about in the future